# Data frame with matrix embedded in one variable

Tags: r, matrix, data-structures, dataframe

I'm using 'pls' package and for this I need to produce a dataframe with a structure a bit different to what I'm used to.

## Data frame structure I need to work with 'pls: gasoline

```
library(pls)
gasoline
```

## Example to show how my data looks like: gasoline2

Background info - What I tend to do to load data into R is to transcript the data in a .xls and then convert the file to a .txt which is then loaded to R.

When my data is loaded it looks like this:

```
gasoline2 <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(gasoline))
```

## Question

How can convert the structure of gasoline2 into the structure of gasoline?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: Why do you tend to write it into Excel?

Comment: I find it easier to introduce the data for the first time... Do you introduce your data differently? :)

Comment: How would I do what? Who you introducing it to? I'm usually using `View` in order to take a look at the data.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, have you tried using `View` on a dataset that has a matrix as a column? :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto I still don't see the point in using Excel. One could simply do `gasoline2 <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(gasoline)) ; View(gasoline2)` or am I missing something here?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, On that part, no. But most of the people I actually work with don't use R, so it's likely I'll give them a CSV even if I'm doing my work in R. Whatever the case, I don't think the question is about Excel, but about achieving this particular data structure. Excel just happens to be in the way here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `I`, which will allow you to combine different data structures (like `list`s or matrices) as columns in a `data.frame`:

```
## Assume you are starting with this:
X <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(gasoline))

## Create a new object where column 1 is the same as the first
##   column in your existing data frame, and column 2 is a matrix
##   of the remaining columns
newGas <- cbind(X[1], NIR = I(as.matrix(X[-1])))
str(gasoline)
# 'data.frame': 60 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ octane: num  85.3 85.2 88.5 83.4 87.9 ...
#  $ NIR   : AsIs [1:60, 1:401] -0.050193 -0.044227 -0.046867 -0.046705 -0.050859 ...
#   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   .. ..$ : chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
#   .. ..$ : chr  "900 nm" "902 nm" "904 nm" "906 nm" ...
str(newGas)
# 'data.frame': 60 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ octane: num  85.3 85.2 88.5 83.4 87.9 ...
#  $ NIR   : AsIs [1:60, 1:401] -0.050193 -0.044227 -0.046867 -0.046705 -0.050859 ...
#   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   .. ..$ : chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
#   .. ..$ : chr  "NIR.900 nm" "NIR.902 nm" "NIR.904 nm" "NIR.906 nm" ...
```

There's a slight difference in the column naming, but I think that can easily be taken care of...

```
> colnames(newGas$NIR) <- gsub("NIR.", "", colnames(newGas$NIR))
> identical(gasoline, newGas)
[1] TRUE
```